# Multiplication operator $M_\phi$

Tags: functional-analysis

I'm studying Functional Analysis by myself. I have a question which may be a simple question.
Let $(X,\Omega,\mu)$ be a finite measure space,$\phi \in L^\infty(\mu)$, and$M_\phi\in B(L^2(\mu))$ be a multiplication operator.I can not show $||M_\phi||>||\phi||_\infty$ and if $M^2_\phi=M_\phi$ then $\phi$ is a charateristic function.

Please help me. Thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

The former is not true, for example if you take $\phi=1$ then $M_\phi$ is just the identity and you have $\lVert M_\phi\rVert=1=\lVert \phi\rVert_\infty$.

For the latter, consider $M_\phi(1)$ and $M_\phi^2(1)$.

Comment: tomasz: I can show $||M_\phi||\leq||\phi||_\infty$. I just couldn't show $||M_\phi||\geq||\phi||_\infty$

Comment: @nika Consider $M_\phi(1)$. Note, that $1 \in L^2(\mu)$, as $(X, \Omega, \mu)$ is finite.

Comment: @nika: But you asked how  to show $\lVert M_\phi\rVert>\lVert \phi\rVert$! this is clearly not true. To show inequality, $M_\phi(1)$ is a good choice.